# Add Salesforce SDK to an existing iOS (Objetive C) project. How to do it?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, sdk

I have a stable project on iOS, with Objetive C.
I use **cocoapods**.

This is my **podFile**:

```
“
platform :ios, 7.0
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0rc'
pod 'FMDB'
# pod 'FMDB/FTS'                # FMDB with FTS
# pod 'FMDB/standalone'         # FMDB with latest SQLite amalgamation source
# pod 'FMDB/standalone/FTS'     # FMDB with latest SQLite amalgamation source and FTS
pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher'            # FMDB with SQLCipher
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'           #Fichero de log dentro de la app   https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack
pod 'mailcore2-ios'                #Enviar ficheros de log por correo
pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'    #OCR 
“
```

I can install Salesforce SDK with pods, without any problem:

```
“
target 'andromedaTecnico' do

    source 'https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Specs.git' # need to be first
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

    use_frameworks!
    pod 'SalesforceSDKCore'
    pod 'SalesforceNetwork'
    pod 'SalesforceRestAPI'
    pod 'SmartStore'
    pod 'SmartSync'


end
pod 'mailcore2-ios'                #Enviar ficheros de log por correo
pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'    #OCR
“
```

But, when I try to use a class, `SalesforceSDKManager` by example, I obtain some errors.

I followed this articles:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/ios_cocoapods.htm

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SalesforceSDKManager”

I tried a lot of things, configurations, … and always I have new and different errors.

Have I forgotten any step?

Thanks a lot.

PD:  **I use El Capitan, Xcode 7, Objetive C and I can´t change to Swift.**

Answer (score 3):

I've done this a few times - added the Salesforce iOS SDK to my existing apps. There's actually a [tutorial](http://quintonwall.github.io/add-mobilesdk-to-project/index.html) which my good friend [Quinton Wall](https://twitter.com/quintonwall) wrote for this. The key steps which you may be missing are

- Adding a Bridging Header
- Configuring your AppDelegate

Once these are done, you also need to ensure (quoting from the tutorial)

> Then, to handle to end of the authentication flow, specify that your
>   View Controller is a delegate for the MobileSDK:
>
> ```
> class MyViewController: UIViewController, SFAuthenticationManagerDelegate
> and implement the Delegate's authManagerDidFinish function.
> ```
>
> I typically check if the username has been populated correctly. If it
>   has, only then do I perform the segue to my HomeController.
>
> The SFAuthenticationManagerDelegate does include a didAuthenticate
>   function which is technically the correct place to perform a check for
>   successful login, however I have found that this method gets called
>   prior to the SDK performing a remove view for the Salesforce login
>   screen. The result is that our newly displayed Home ViewController is
>   removed. :( Within the viewDidLoad method, register this controller as
>   a delegate.

```
SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().addDelegate(self)

func authManagerDidFinish(manager: SFAuthenticationManager!, info: SFOAuthInfo!) {

 if !!SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().haveValidSession {
     //call the segue with the name you give it in the storyboard editor
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: nil)

     //or simply dismiss the login view to return to where you came from
     // self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }
}
```

This should fix it!

Comment: Hello Gaurav Kheterpal   I tried the tutorial from Quinton Wall without success.   I write Quinton by Twitter to get help.          Now, I import SDK with pod and another libraries, but I can´t use FMDB outside SmartStore.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124465/can-i-use-fmdb-libraries-from-smartstore              Thanks.